# Int to char conversion while still using %c in the c language

Tags: c, char

I have the following code.

```
int ant = 10;
char converter = ant;
printf("This is where the char prints: %c", converter);
```

Why does the console only print out when this is run:

```
This is where the char prints:
```

Why does this happen? And is it possible to still use the %c and print out the value?
I understand that changing the %c to a %d will allow me to see the result but i wanna know why.

Comment: It' because the ASCII character with value 10 is just a newline

Comment: So is there a way to convert the int to a char? So that i can still use the %c when printing?

Comment: what output exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JaneDoe `1` and `0` would be 2 chars, not one. What exactly are you trying to do, convert an integer to a string?

Comment: In an ASCII based computer `10` and `'\n'` in source code are totally 100% absolutely equal. They both have type `int` and they have the same value.

Answer (score 6):

You are printing out the character *encoded* by the number 10: the format specifier `%c` is used to output the characters, rather than their numerical values.

In ASCII (most likely the encoding used), that's `\n`; the linefeed character. Your terminal is probably able to deal with that, and you'll see an extra line in your output.

If you want to print the numeric value of `converter`, then use simply `%d` as the format specifier (the `char` types are converted implicitly to `int` types at the calling site).

Comment: So is there a way to convert the int to a char? So that i can still use the %c when printing?

Comment: @JaneDoe: Added at the end.

Comment: @JaneDoe - `%c` is for printing a *single character*. If you expect it (a single `%c`) to output `10` (two characters) there is no way to make it happen.